# How to check the day name from date. but from procedure I have getting wrong day as per the date so please help me

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my SQL Server code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetLeaveDateBewteenStartAndEndDate]      
    (@UserEmail VARCHAR(100) = NULL,      
     @FromDate VARCHAR(10) = NULL,      
     @ToDate VARCHAR(10) = NULL)      
AS      
BEGIN      
    --SELECT       
    --GETDATE() AS [Date]      
    --,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103) AS ShortDate      
    --,'Monday' as [DayName]      
    --,'Full Day' as [Session]      
    --, 1 as NoOfDays      
    --,'Work Day' as [Status]      
    --,'W' as StatusCode      
    
     DECLARE @Result AS TABLE    
                        (    
                            Date       DATETIME,
                            ShortDate  VARCHAR(50),
                            DayNames   VARCHAR(50),    
                            Session    VARCHAR(20),    
                            NoOfDays   INT,
                            Status     VARCHAR(50),    
                            StatusCode VARCHAR(2)    
                        )        
       
    DECLARE @dayscount INT 

    SET @dayscount =  CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, @FromDate, 103), CONVERT(DATE, @ToDate, 103)) AS INT) + 1

    DECLARE @daysval INT
    SET @daysval = 0

    WHILE (@daysval < @dayscount)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Result (Date, ShortDate, DayNames, Session, NoOfDays, Status, StatusCode)    
        VALUES (CONVERT(DATETIME, DATEADD(DAY, @daysval, CONVERT(DATE, @FromDate, 103)), 103), CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DATEADD(DAY, @daysval, CONVERT(DATE, @FromDate, 103)), 103),     
                DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DATEADD(DAY, @daysval, '07/02/2021'), 103)), 
                'Full Session', 1, 'Work Day', 'W')    
    
        SET @daysval = @daysval + 1

        DECLARE @daycheck NVARCHAR(100)

        SELECT @daycheck = DayNames 
        FROM @Result
   
        IF (@daycheck = 'sunday')
        BEGIN
            UPDATE @Result
            SET Status = '', StatusCode = ''
        END
    END
      
    SELECT * FROM @Result   
END
```

And after executing my query, I get this result:

```
EXEC [dbo].[usp_GetLeaveDateBewteenStartAndEndDate] NULL, '03/02/2021', '05/02/2021'

Date    ShortDate   DayNames    Session NoOfDays    Status  StatusCode  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-03 00:00:00.000 03/02/2021  Sunday  Full Session    1       
2021-02-04 00:00:00.000 04/02/2021  Sunday  Full Session    1       
2021-02-05 00:00:00.000 05/02/2021  Wednesday   Full Session    1   Work Day    W
```

For 01/02/2021, `daynames` should be Monday and 05/02/2021 should be Tuesday.

Comment: Why on earth are you converting dates to `varchar` only to pass them back to date functions, keep dates as dates. And you need to learn how to use a tally table/function.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure why you are seeing those results as I don't have your input parameters. But there are **a number of fundamental errors** in your code.

1. `select @daycheck = DayNames from @Result` does not check which row it is asking for.
2. `update @Result set Status = '' , StatusCode = ''` has the same problem.
3. You are converting dates to `varchar` left and right. **Keep values in the format they are supposed to be**, and just convert where necessary for displaying.
4. Furthermore, you should be passing through the From and To dates as `date` not `varchar`.
5. There is no need for a `while` loop or a table variable to do all this. **It can be done with a tally table.** I have used [Itzik Ben-Gan's well-known one](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1) below.

```sql
WITH
    L0 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c) ),
    L1 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B ),
    L2 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B ),
    L3 AS ( SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B ),
    Nums AS ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
              FROM L3 ),
    Dates AS (
        SELECT TOP( DATEDIFF(day, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1 )
            DATEADD(day, rownum - 1, @FromDate) AS dateVal
        FROM Nums
    )

SELECT
    dateVal AS Date,
    CONVERT(Varchar(50), dateVal, 103) AS ShortDate,
    v.DayNames,
    'Full Session' AS Session,
    1 AS NoOfDays,
    CASE WHEN v.DayNames = 'Sunday' THEN '' ELSE 'Work Day' END AS Status,
    CASE WHEN v.DayNames = 'Sunday' THEN '' ELSE 'W' END AS StatusCode
FROM Dates
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATENAME(dw, dateVal) ) ) AS v(DayNames)
```

Comment: the output is okay but problem is the date 03/02/2021 and 04/02/2021 both are dayname is showing Wednesday, but 04.02.2021 will be Thursday. day names cannot be change thats is my problem update is working. please help me for dayname which are not populate with correct data

Comment: Sorry I get `04/02/2021   |     Thursday`, are you changing my code in anyway other than the parameters?

Comment: your code output is okay, but when I pass the parameter '10/02/2021'  DD/MM/YYYY as from date in your code its taken as '02/10/2021' I need same format

Comment: That is to do with your server settings, which are probably on US settings. Always write date literals in an unambiguous format `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` to prevent confusion. Declare your parameters as `@FromDate date` not `varchar`